# Rate of exponential decay

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, exponential-function

Good day all

I have this curve (it is a solution of a partial differential equation that am working on)

[image: exponential decay plot]

and I want to calculate numerically the rate of exponential decay but I don't know how to go about it. Is there a way to do this with Matlab? or is there any other way to calculate the rate of exponential decay for it? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$f(t)$ decaying (or growing) exponentially for all $t > t_0$ means that there are parameters $c,\lambda$ such that $$
  f(t) = c\,e^{\lambda (t-t_0)} \text{ for $t > t_0$.}
$$

Now put an logarithmic scaled on the $y$-axis, i.e. instead of $f$, we look at the function $$
  \hat f(t) = \ln f(t) = \ln c + \ln e^{\lambda(t-t0_0)} = \ln c + \lambda (t-t_0) = \lambda t + \ln c - \lambda t_0 \text{,}
$$
which means that $\hat t$ will then be a *line* with slope $\lambda$.

Thus, you can numerically find the rate of decay by fitting a line to the *logarithmn* of the samples of $f$ you computed.

---

If you really want to do non-linear regression (by the look of your curve, linear regression should work quite well!), you can use matlab's `lsqcurvefit` function. You'll need to provide it with the parametrized objective function you want to fit, and preferrably with it's jacobi matrix (otherwise, the algorithms must resort to numeric differentiation, which is always a bit troublesome). Our objective function is $$
  F\left((c,\lambda),t\right) = c\, e^{\lambda t}
$$
and has the partial derivatives $$\begin{eqnarray}
  \frac{\partial F}{\partial c} &=& e^{\lambda t} &\quad&
  \frac{\partial F}{\partial \lambda} &=& c\lambda e^{\lambda t} \text{.}
\end{eqnarray}$$
The following matlab function computes both

```
# Evaluates F((c,lambda), t)
#   Argument p are the parameters, i.e. p(1) = c, p(2) = lambda
#   Argument ts is a vector (or matrix) of t-values at which we evaluate F
#   Return value F(i) is F(p,ts(i))
#   Return value J(i) is [dF/dc (p,ts(i)), dF/dlambda (p,ts(i))]
function [F,J] = myF(p, ts)
  c = p(1)
  lambda = p(2)
  F = c * exp(lambda * ts)
  J = reshape([
    exp(lambda * ts),
    c * lambda * exp(lambda * ts)
  ], numel(ts), 2)
```

You can then use this with `lsqcurvefit` by doing

```
opts = optimoptions('lsqcurvefit','Jacobian','on')
p = lsqcurvefit(@myF, [1,-1], xvalues, yvalues, [], [], opts)
```

Note that this is mostly off the top of my head, and I haven't actually tried it. So there might be syntax errors and other mistakes in this code.

Comment: This will give a good estimate of the parameters. But I suggest that the values be polished using a nonlinear regression. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Whether that helps or hurts depends on the nature of the errors of the samples. If their *relative* errors are bounded for all of them, then I think linear regression on the logarithm gives the best result, because directly applying non-linear regression will put too little weight in deviations at the right end of the curve. If, OTOH, the absolute error is bounded, then the logarithm will basically amplify noise at the right end of the curve, and non-linear regression will work better.

Comment: I agree with you. For this kind of problems, what I use to do is to minimize the sum of the squares of relative errors. It is easy to show that, if the errors are small, this SSQ is very close to the one obtained for the logarithmic transform.

Comment: Thank you guys for your suggestions.Linear regression did not really work because the residual norm was so high about 31.8.I wanted to try nonlinear regression but don't know how to get the rate of exponential decay can anyone tell me how?

Comment: @Jamin You did the linear regressio on the *logarithm* of the data, right? From the look of your curve, it's hard to image that this wouldn't work.... Anyway, I've added a section explaining the basics of non-linear regression with matlab (or any other piece of software, really)